# How can I switch keyboards using gesture navigation only(no navigation bar)? (OnePlus 5t)

Tags: buttons, operating-system, gestures, oneplus-5t

I recently decided to try out gesture navigation on Android (with the navigation bar turned off), and I liked it so much I decided to do away with my navigation bar for good.

Aside from English, I type Mandarin on my phone every day, and need to switch keyboards repeatedly during the day or even the span of a few minutes. Unfortunately, I used to use the keyboard button on the nav bar to switch keyboards, and now Ihave to drag down the notification bar, tap change keyboards, and then choose keyboard.

Is there a gesture I can use to do the same thing instead? Haven't been able to find any reference to what gesture might, if any, have replaced the nav button.

I'm on a Oneplus 5t, Android 8.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Some keyboards may provide such features. E.g., Gboard allows you to hold the spacebar to bring up different languages and input methods. I've tried some Chinese keyboards as well, but I don't remember any implementing this feature, as they prefer to lock you into their own keyboard. So, for now, I guess you have a few options:

1. Stick to one keyboard that offers all languages and features you would like to use (hardest),
2. Find keyboards that implement keyboard-switching shortcuts,
3. Use a more customizable gesture navigation system that allows you to associate some gesture with keyboard switching instead of the built-in one, or
4. Live with the current situation.

Answer (score 1):

Android 9 "improved" this problem, as navigation bar is default hidden.

My Bank app has a feature which is a keyboard and helps a lot to make payments during chats in WhatsApp and SMS, but now it's impossible to use, because is impossible to change keyboards, if I want to stay with navigation bar hidden and with samsung keyboard.